# I am working on 'https://berkeleyai.github.io/cs188-website/project3.html' reinforcement learning in Pacman project

Tags: python, bash, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

In this project we are asked to will implement value iteration and Q-learning, and test our agents first on Gridworld (from class), then apply them to a simulated robot controller (Crawler) and Pacman. The instructions are to download a zip folder and edit the valueIterationAgents.py and qlearningAgents.py which I have completed, but when I run commands like:

```
python gridworld.py -m
python gridworld.py -a value -i 100 -k 10
python pacman.py -p PacmanQAgent -x 2000 -n 2010 -l smallGrid
```

on bash terminal I get this error

```
python: can't open file 'Pacman.py':[Errno 1] Operation not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving my file from downloads to desktop